# How to configure different networks for host and VM with UTM?

Tags: network, apple-silicon, virtualization

I have two networks: a wifi network and an USBC-connected Android device tethering 4G.

Both connections are working. I'd like to have 2 different public IP addresses.

How can I get my UTM VM to use the USB connection, and my host the wifi?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution seems to be to connect the Android device as a USB-device inside the UTM VM. I.e. instead of letting the host system see the USB device and setup tethering - then let the UTM VM see the USB device and set up tethering.

Comment: I didn't think of that. It's working obviously. Thanks!